# Why is loading addressables 20x slower for an Android app bundle?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, async-await

At the start of my Unity Android game I load all prefabs via addressables:

```
await Task.WhenAll(retrievePrefabsTasks);
```

When I deploy directly to my Android device via Unity, this takes about 10s.

When I instead build an app bundle, upload it to Google Play and then install it on the same device, prefab loading takes over 3 minutes.

What could be causing this?

---

**Edit**

My Unity build settings when building an .aab:

[image: Unity Android build settings for AAB]

Comment: By deploy you mean actually deploy or just remote renderer?

Comment: Actually deploy.  I can see my app installed on my Android device, unplug the device from the computer and launch the app fine.

Comment: Is the compression/encryption different when you build for play store?

Comment: Hm, not that I know of :/  The only setting I change to create an aab is "Build App Bundle (Google Play)" (see screenshot).  I don't touch the "Texture Compression" or "Compression Method" settings.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be [a Unity bug](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-loading-assets-from-assetbundles-takes-significantly-more-time-when-the-project-is-built-as-an-aab?_ga=2.204359632.1780692621.1608559324-1767580709.1595774341) that has been fixed.

Can confirm that updating my Unity version from 2019.2.21f1 to 2020.1.17f1 fixed the issue.